# How to subset the most recent 12 months of data for each ID in a data frame?

Tags: r, date, subset

I have a data frame representing 15 years of follow-up data from several hundred patients.  I want to create a subset of the data frame including the most recent 12 months of data for each patient.

Here is a representative example of my data (including one missing value, because missing data abound in my actual dataset):

```
# Create example dataset.
example.dat <- data.frame(
  ID = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), # patient ID numbers
  Date = as.Date(c("2000-02-01", "2004-10-21", "2005-02-06", # follow-up dates
                   "2005-06-14", "2002-11-24", "2009-03-05",
                   "2009-07-20", "2005-09-02", "2006-01-15",
                   "2006-05-18")),
  Cat = c("Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", # responses to a categorical variable
          "Yes", "Yes", NA,   "No", "No")
  )

example.dat
```

Which yields the following output:

```
   ID       Date  Cat
1   1 2000-02-01  Yes
2   1 2004-10-21  Yes
3   1 2005-02-06   No
4   1 2005-06-14  Yes
5   2 2002-11-24   No
6   2 2009-03-05  Yes
7   2 2009-07-20  Yes
8   3 2005-09-02 <NA>
9   3 2006-01-15   No
10  3 2006-05-18   No
```

I need to figure out how to subset, for each ID number, the most recent record and all records from the previous 12 months.

```
   ID       Date  Cat
2   1 2004-10-21  Yes
3   1 2005-02-06   No
4   1 2005-06-14  Yes
6   2 2009-03-05  Yes
7   2 2009-07-20  Yes
8   3 2005-09-02 <NA>
9   3 2006-01-15   No
10  3 2006-05-18   No
```

Several questions have already been asked about subsetting by date in R, but they are generally concerned with subsetting data from a specific date or range of dates, not subsetting by ((variable end date) - (time interval)).

Answer (score 5):

For the sake of completeness, here are two `data.table` approaches using either subsetting by groups or a *non-equi join*. In addition, `lubridate` is used to ensure a period of 12 months is picked even in the case of leap years.

#### Subsetting by groups

This is essentialy the `data.table` version of [docendo discimus' `dplyr` answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24959598/3817004). However, `lubridate` functions are used for date arithmetic because simply subtracting 365 days will not cover a period of 12 months as requested by the OP in case the past year contains a *leap day*:

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
setDT(example.dat)[, .SD[Date >= max(Date) %m-% years(1)], by = ID]
```

> ```
>    ID       Date Cat
> 1:  1 2004-10-21 Yes
> 2:  1 2005-02-06  No
> 3:  1 2005-06-14 Yes
> 4:  2 2009-03-05 Yes
> 5:  2 2009-07-20 Yes
> 6:  3 2005-09-02  NA
> 7:  3 2006-01-15  No
> 8:  3 2006-05-18  No
> ```

#### Non-equi join

With version [v1.9.8 (on CRAN 25 Nov 2016)](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.0.md#new-features), `data.table` has gained the ability to perform *non-equi joins*:

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
mDT <- setDT(example.dat)[, max(Date) %m-% years(1), by = ID]
example.dat[example.dat[mDT, on = .(ID, Date >= V1), which = TRUE]]
```

> ```
>    ID       Date Cat
> 1:  1 2004-10-21 Yes
> 2:  1 2005-02-06  No
> 3:  1 2005-06-14 Yes
> 4:  2 2009-03-05 Yes
> 5:  2 2009-07-20 Yes
> 6:  3 2005-09-02  NA
> 7:  3 2006-01-15  No
> 8:  3 2006-05-18  No
> ```

`mDT` contains the start dates of the 12 months period for each `ID`:

> ```
>    ID         V1
> 1:  1 2004-06-14
> 2:  2 2008-07-20
> 3:  3 2005-05-18
> ```

The non-equi join returns the indices of the rows which fulfill the conditions

```
example.dat[mDT, on = .(ID, Date >= V1), which = TRUE]
```

> ```
> [1]  2  3  4  6  7  8  9 10
> ```

which are then used to finally subset `example.dat`.

#### Comparison of date arithmetic methods

The answers posted so far employed three different methods to find a date 12 months earlier:

- [docendo discimus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24959598/3817004) subtracts 365 days,
- [G. Grothendieck](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24959450/3817004) uses `seq.Date()`,
- this answer uses `years()` and `%m-%`

The three methods differ in case a leap day is included in the period:

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
mseq <- Vectorize(function(x) seq(x, length = 2L, by = "-1 year")[2L])
data.table(Date = as.Date("2016-02-28") + 0:2)[
  , minus_365d := Date -365][
    , minus_1yr := Date - years()][
      , minus_1yr_m := Date %m-% years()][
        , seq.Date := as_date(mseq(Date))][]
```

> ```
>          Date minus_365d  minus_1yr minus_1yr_m   seq.Date
> 1: 2016-02-28 2015-02-28 2015-02-28  2015-02-28 2015-02-28
> 2: 2016-02-29 2015-03-01       <NA>  2015-02-28 2015-03-01
> 3: 2016-03-01 2015-03-02 2015-03-01  2015-03-01 2015-03-01
> ```

- If there is `no` leap day in the past period, all three methods return the same result (row 1).
- If a leap day is included in the past period, subtracting 365 days does not fully cover 12 months (row 3) as a leap year has 366 days.
- If the reference date *is* a leap date, the `seq.Date()` approach picks the next day, 1 March 2015, as there is no 29 February in 2015. Using `lubridate`'s `%m-%` rolls the date to the last day of February, 28 Feb 2015, instead.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a base solution.  We have `ave` operate on dates as numbers since if we were to use raw `"Date"` values `ave` would try to return `"Date"` values.  Instead, `ave` returns 0/1 values and `!!` converts those to FALSE/TRUE.

```
 in_last_yr <- function(x) {
    max_date <- as.Date(max(x), "1970-01-01")
    x > seq(max_date, length = 2, by = "-1 year")[2]
 }
 subset(example.dat, !!ave(as.numeric(Date), ID, FUN = in_last_yr))
```

**Update**  Improved method of determining which days are in last year.

Answer (score 2):

A possible approach using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

example.dat %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter(Date >= max(Date)-365)

#Source: local data frame [8 x 3]
#Groups: ID
#
#  ID       Date Cat
#1  1 2004-10-21 Yes
#2  1 2005-02-06  No
#3  1 2005-06-14 Yes
#4  2 2009-03-05 Yes
#5  2 2009-07-20 Yes
#6  3 2005-09-02  NA
#7  3 2006-01-15  No
#8  3 2006-05-18  No
```